# Lifetimes and ownership with traits

Tags: rust, traits

I am building a Rocket app and want it to manage some objects for me. For that, they need to be `Send` and `Sync`. Here's a minimal contrived example that shows the error I am getting ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2192b5497866640ea310672e63e8303)):

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

struct TraitThing {}

impl MyTrait for TraitThing {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Foo!");
    }
}

struct Thing {
    tt: &'static (dyn MyTrait + Send + Sync),
}

impl Thing {
    fn with_trait(tt: &'static (dyn MyTrait + Send + Sync)) -> Self {
        Self { tt }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tt = TraitThing {};
    let thing = Thing::with_trait(&tt);
    thing.tt.foo();
}
```

I probably don't understand lifetimes of `'static`. Ideally, I want `Thing` to own `tt`, but as far as I understand, since my TraitThing isn't `Sized` (and probably won't ever be), it cannot be a trait object, so it must be passed by reference.

So, how do I solve this while keeping the `Send` and `Sync` traits?

Thanks!

Additional note: I've been reading a lot about lifetimes and traits in the Rust book and other places, but I'd appreciate further reading material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html):

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

struct TraitThing {}

impl MyTrait for TraitThing {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Foo!");
    }
}

struct Thing {
    tt: Box<dyn MyTrait + Send + Sync>,
}

impl Thing {
    fn with_trait(tt: Box<dyn MyTrait + Send + Sync>) -> Self {
        Self { tt }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tt = TraitThing {};
    let thing = Thing::with_trait(Box::new(tt));
    thing.tt.foo();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de82cc8e07e8b86a311bb4096e80d71e)

Comment: Thank you, I like easy solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Box** but it will allocate to the Heap and use dynamic dispatch which is not useful in your case. It is useful when you want a list of different type that implements a similar Trait like :

```rust
struct Thing {
    tt: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait + Send + Sync>>,
}
```

But in your case you only have one element so you can use **Generics** in this setup:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

struct TraitThing {}

impl MyTrait for TraitThing {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Foo!");
    }
}

struct Thing<T>
where
    T: MyTrait + Send + Sync
{
    tt: T,
}

impl<T> Thing<T> 
where
    T: MyTrait + Send + Sync
{
    fn with_trait(tt: T) -> Self {
        Self { tt }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tt = TraitThing {};
    let thing = Thing::with_trait(tt);
    thing.tt.foo();
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting! I'll have to read more about that.

Comment: Hm, how does this even work? I thought the problem with a dynamic type is that the size is not known at compile time, thus the Box, whose size is known. How does the compiler know the size this way? I guess it's not marked `dyn`...

Comment: Ah okay, I think I get it. I could make more `Thing`s with different structs that are `MyTrait`, and the compiler would generate each `Thing` to match the type of that specific `MyTrait` struct at compile time. So this works as long as the same `Thing` doesn't need different `MyTrait` structs at runtime. Nice!

Comment: Yes that exactly it